# Do I need to "unregister" an OSX virtual machine?

Tags: macos, vmware, virtualization

I have an OSX VM (using VMWare fusion 6), and want to delete it.

[VMWare's docs](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2005334) say "Apple's updated license agreement allows you to install up to two additional copies of Lion on your Mac which is already running a retail version of Lion"

I remember something in the installation, possibly linking to my Apple ID saying that I could only install 1-2 copies in a VM too (I installed Mavericks, 10.9)

If I'm going to delete this VM, and want to create other OSX VMs in the future, can I/do I need to "unregister" this VM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no registration for OS X, and nothing in the code to detect and prevent you running more than two VMs. It's purely a legal restriction. If you've deleted the VM, then you're fine.